# how to disable (uninstall) the old `mix phoenix`?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

Coming back into phoenix after a while; I still have an install from the "previous 1.3" hanging around

Which lead to some "nice" issues trying to understand what was happening; because reading here and there, some tells you to use `mix phoenix...`, some other (more recent) tells you to run `mix phx...`

The problem is, those two commands does not end with the same result

`mix phoenix.gen.json` works, but you get the old web folder; while `mix phx.gen.json` puts you on the correct path

I could live off that by remembering to never type mix.phoenix; but still, I'd be looking to find a way to make my workstation unable to run those misleading `mix phoenix...`

I'm still new to this ecosystem; just don't have a clue where to search to clean this install

best;

Comment: According to [this](https://elixirforum.com/t/phx-new-vs-phoenix-new/10988/3), `mix archive.uninstall phoenix.new` should do the trick.

Comment: nope :/ `Could not find a local artifact named "phoenix.new".` found those : `* hex-0.18.1
* phoenix_new
* phx_new` but even running `mix archive.uninstall phoenix_new` does not solve this issue

Comment: =/. I see you joined the discussion on the elixir forums. If you find a solution remember to post it here. :)

Comment: @bla well it ended up that there were not solution for now (at least until 1.4), but oke day later i guess that's not a big deal (;

Comment: Just to add more resources:

Both tasks are defined on the 1.3 as we can see [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/tree/v1.3/lib/mix/tasks).

As you mentioned the new version will remove it as we can see [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/tree/master/lib/mix/tasks).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by writing the following in your terminal:

```
mix archive uninstall phoenix_new
```

You can confirm it has been removed by attempting to run:

```
mix phoenix.new hello
```

You should get an error that says:

> ** (Mix) The task “phoenix.new” could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall phoenix:

```
mix archive.uninstall phx_new
```